# How can i unmashaller that xml stream. Getting null values

Tags: xml, jaxb

[image]StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreditTransferTransactionInformation2.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            CreditTransferTransactionInformation2 transaction = (CreditTransferTransactionInformation2) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot adding getValue at the end because you obtain a JAXBElement.

```
public class XmlManager<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    public XmlManager(Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    }
    public T unmarshal(String xml) throws JAXBException {
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), clazz).getValue();
    }
}
```